# How can I add a title above the first row using Prototype cells?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have a iPhone app using Prototype cells in a UITableViewController. I want to put a title right above the first row (where it says Prototype Cells). How do I do this? (Ignore what's in the first row...that's what I want the title to say)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to use dynamic prototypes cells, not static cells, it's best to do this in code.  Override the method

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

in your table view controller and return the title you want for each section. If you only plan to have one section, then it's as easy as

```
return NSLocalizedString(@"Title for Section", @"");
```

But then if you only have one section, it may be bad UI design to label it, depending on what it is you're doing...

Comment: That worked great!  However, is there a way to get two (2) lines of title?  (as shown in the yellow row above)?

Comment: For that, there's viewForHeaderInSection:, but you;ll have to create the view somewhere and add labels to it.